# Python code error (scalar arrays to scalar index)

Tags: python

I faced a problem in a python script..

I run it as :

```
python /path/script.py
```

it gave me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/script.py", line 332, in <module>
    main()
File "/path/script.py", line 283, in main
    hull1.append(points3[hullIndex[i]])
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

this is a part of code (from line 262 to 284) :

```
    #Following steps detects again the original face using dlib, this time for do face swapping
    #target face is the frame taken from camera and source face is the one morphed before
    dets4 = detector(img4, 1)
    if len(dets4)<1:
        pass
    else:
        for k, d in enumerate(dets4):
            points3 = []
            #Get 68 facial landmarks and save them to an array
            landmark3=np.array([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(img4, dets4[0]).parts()])
            for i in range(0,68) :
                x3 = landmark3[i][0]
                y3 = landmark3[i][1]
                points3.append((int(x3), int(y3)))

    # Find convex hull
    hull1 = []
    hull2 = []
    hullIndex = cv2.convexHull(np.array(points2), returnPoints = False)

    for i in xrange(0, len(hullIndex)):
        hull1.append(points3[hullIndex[i]])
        hull2.append(points2[hullIndex[i]])
```

and from (line 330 to 339) :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except ValueError:
        img2 = cv2.resize(img2,(320,320))
        swap = cv2.resize(swap,(320,320))
        dst = cv2.addWeighted(img2,0.55,swap,0.45,0)
        cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[3], dst)
        print "Shutting down"
    print "Exit"
```

Is there any part of these codes need to be fixed, or it is something related to other things (like python, dlib, any module versions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.convexHull()` with `returnPoints=False` returns a list of point indices, however each index is contained in another sublist like this: `[[index1], [index2], ...]`

So you can simplify these lines

```
for i in xrange(0, len(hullIndex)):
    hull1.append(points3[hullIndex[i]])
    hull2.append(points2[hullIndex[i]])
```

to

```
for point_index, in hullIndex:
    hull1.append(points3[point_index])
    hull2.append(points2[point_index])
```

See the tutorial on [Contour Features](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks you so much, you are amazing :)